# How to control scroll view of sdk:DataGrid in Silverlight 4.0?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I have a page called Personal Info which has DataGrid which has huge data.

[image]

For Example, User wants to update Customer ID - "GALED", On double click of that row it'll pop up Update Page which shows data related to Customer ID - "GALED". After updation the Personal Info page gets refreshed so that the changes will be reflected. But because of that it resets the position of scroll and every time the user has to scroll it down to update next data, in this case Customer ID - "FURIB".

I need code which will automatically set Scroll to previous position so that user don't have scroll it down.

Comment: Maybe adding a bit of what you have done might help?

Comment: @Tavo I want to add image but Stack is not letting me add it as I don't have 10 reputation. Can you help me?